# Is there a ASN.1 reparser / compound ASN.1 display tool?

Tags: asn.1

I'm writing a standard / reference implementation of (certain aspects of) CMS (Cryptographic Message Syntax, RFC 5652), described across several tens of RFC's, where some of the ASN.1 goes back for decades. I'm banging my head against the wall with the amount of tabs I have to have open in my browser at any given time, and the amount of searching I have to do, simply to assemble how certain structures work their way down into all of their various subtypes.

And then I'm thinking: it's 2018. It's almost 2019 - somebody must have had the idea by now, that you can simply filter all of that stuff out of all of those RFC's, and create a notation for how all of these structures are /really/ put together, from top (structures that have no parent) to bottom (scalars). I have no luck in finding such a tool, however. Perhaps someone here has an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, but I can suspect that you are looking for a complete ASN structure definitions for x.509 and CMS in single place? If yes, then you may look at RFC 5912: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5912

Comment: Thank - that was a great answer. Although it is already somewhat older (RFC 6010 - which I have the most issues with now, is not in it, for example). Follow up question: is there someone who just manages the 'holistic view' of CMS permanently?